# define_table does not create table in database

Tags: python, web2py

I am running `define_tables` in the recommended way:

```
db = DAL('postgres://user:XXXX@localhost:5432/mydb', migrate_enabled=False, auto_import=False, lazy_tables=True)
db.define_table('auth_user',
    Field('email', unique=True),
    Field('password', length=512, type='password', readable=False, label='Password'),
    ...)
```

This gets executed without errors, but no table is created in the database. Whenever I try to insert a new user:

```
relation "auth_user" does not exist
```

What can be going on? Once the tables are created (manually, for example), the application works fine. I am using a postgres backend. This happens no matter what value I give to `lazy_tables`

### EDIT

This is the full test script:

```
from gluon import DAL
from gluon import Field

db = DAL('postgres://user:pass@localhost:5432/mydb', migrate_enabled=False)

db.define_table(
    'auth_user',
    Field('email',              type='string', unique=True),
    Field('password',           type='password'),
    Field('registration_key',   type='string',   length=512, writable=False, readable=False, default=''),
    Field('reset_password_key', type='string',   length=512, writable=False, readable=False, default=''),
    Field('registration_id',    type='string',   length=512, writable=False, readable=False, default=''),
)
db.commit()

print db.tables

db.auth_user.insert(email='g@b.c')
```

And I get the following output:

```
['auth_user']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx.py", line 19, in <module>
    db.auth_user.insert(email='g@b.c')
  File "/tmp/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 9293, in insert
    ret =  self._db._adapter.insert(self, self._listify(fields))
  File "/tmp/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 1361, in insert
    raise e
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO auth_user(reset_password_key,registration_id,reg...
```

The table is somehow "created" (in memory?), but it is not really in the postgres database. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove `migrate_enabled=False`, which turns off migrations and therefore prevents the creation or modification of database tables. There is also no need to explicitly set `auto_import=False` as that is already the default.

If the above doesn't help, it is possible that web2py did successfully create such a table previously and it was removed without web2py knowing about it. If the application's `/databases` folder includes a file with a name like *_auth_user.table, delete that file and try again.

If that's not the issue, check the `/databases/sql.log` file and confirm that web2py attempted to create the table. Most likely, something in your system configuration is preventing the table from being created.

**UPDATE**: From your edit, it appears you are using the DAL outside of a web2py application. Because you have not specified the `folder` argument to the `DAL()` constructor, it will save the *.table migration files in the current working directory, and it will not create a sql.log file. In this case, it is best to create a separate folder for the migration and log files:

```
DAL('postgres://user:pass@localhost:5432/mydb', folder='/path/to/folder')
```

In that case, it will save all of the *.table migration files and the sql.log file in the specified folder.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, this is very helpful to further diagnose my problem.

Comment: One question about this: *which turns off migrations and therefore prevents the creation or modification of database tables*: does `migrate_enabled=False` also prevents *creation*? In my understanding, a creation is not a migration.

Comment: The term "migration" does not only refer to alterations of individual tables (such as adding new columns) but to any alterations of the database schema (which includes adding new tables). This is described in the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Migrations), and I think it is consistent with how the term is used in other frameworks. A migration is just a change from one version of the database schema to another -- after creating a new table, you now have a new database schema (i.e., you have "migrated" to a new version of the schema).